# iOS - Unity build error - Durovis SDK

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have just purchased an iOS developer account and I want to create iOS VR apps with Unity3D. I know that Google Cardboard SDK does not support iOS, so I downloaded and tried Durovis SDK.

Once I imported the durovis `.unitypackage` , I made an empty build, just so I could test out if it builds through Xcode. 
The result is that Xcode fails to build when I choose "Device SDK" from Unity build settings , and succeeds when I choose "Simulator SDK" but of course then it runs on Simulator and not on my device.

I am very new to Xcode, so I don't know if I need to import anything from Xcode, after I make the build from Unity. Any help would be appreciated, since I've been making VR apps long time now for android and I recently decided to try to ios as well. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version. Then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bring up the PlayerSettings. Make sure company name and product name are filled in and then scroll down and click `Other Settings`. For the bundle identifier it has to be `com.companyName.ProductName` and that should be it. If that doesn't work you'll have to tweak xCode settings but that's more fragile so please respond to this with results or lack thereof.